How to make unwraps for a non-square UV not stretched?
I'm making a model with a 1:4 UV map ratio. I know that I can simply scale all the UVs by 4x on the X plane, but that's only useful if I'm actually done making the model. If I ever want to unwrap again while the UV is 1:4, it makes it stretched. Checking the "Correct Aspect" option doesn't fix it. I'm using normal unwrap, not smart unwrap. How do I make unwraps not stretch when using a non-square UV map?

I would unlink whatever texture you have assigned in the UV unwrap workspace, so that you're unwrapping in a plain default UV space. It should unwrap correctly there. Although I'm half sure that the "stretched UVs" you're seeing in the UV unwrap area is only a representation, it's not actually stretching the UVs. If you unwrap then switch to a square image you'll see it corrects the UVs you see to fit a "square" aspect.
